# CSS :before with content break paddings

Tags: html, css

I have this one with nice spacing, but without labels:

https://jsfiddle.net/my75k9mw/5/

I have this one after adding labels using `:before`:

https://jsfiddle.net/my75k9mw/4/

How can I keep the labels and also have nice spacing as in first example?

My Code:

```css
div.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
  border-style: dashed;
}

div.wrapper:before {
  content: 'FAQ wrapper';
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  color: red;
  background: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

div.wrapper div.item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-style: dashed;
}

div.wrapper div.item:before {
  content: 'FAQ item';
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  color: gray;
  background: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

div.wrapper div.item div.question {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div.wrapper div.item div.question:before {
  content: 'Question';
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  color: gray;
  background: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

div.wrapper div.item div.answer {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 15px;
}

div.eni-faq-wrapper div.eni-faq-item div.eni-faq-answer:before {
  content: 'Answer';
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  color: gray;
  background: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="question">
      <a>I am a question.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <p>I am an answer.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="question">
      <a>I am a question.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <p>I am an answer.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="question">
      <a>I am a question.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <p>I am an answer.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: The HTML need to remain the same in my case.

Comment: try to add `.question:before {
  display: table;
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}` something like that should work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use absolute positioning for the labels:

```css
div.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
  border-style: dashed;
  position: relative;
}

div.wrapper:before {
  content: 'FAQ wrapper';
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: red;
  background: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

div.wrapper div.item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-style: dashed;
  position: relative;
}

div.wrapper div.item:before {
  content: 'FAQ item';
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: gray;
  background: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

div.wrapper div.item div.question {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

div.wrapper div.item div.question:before {
  content: 'Question';
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: gray;
  background: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

div.wrapper div.item div.answer {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

div.wrapper div.item div.answer:before {
  content: 'Answer';
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: gray;
  background: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="question">
      <a>I am a question.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <p>I am an answer.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="question">
      <a>I am a question.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <p>I am an answer.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="question">
      <a>I am a question.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <p>I am an answer.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative;` to `div.wrapper div.item div.question` and `position: absolute;  top: -6px;` to `div.wrapper div.item div.question:before`

https://jsfiddle.net/my75k9mw/20/

Answer (score 1):

Why not making it with `fieldset` + `legend`?

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>I am a question</legend>
  <p>I am an answer</p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: It's a WIP for a tinyMCE plugin. I just add this from CSS to keep the HTML as it is. :)

Comment: So, in view mode I don't want that labels, only for edit mode.

Comment: Who would know you can't change the html from the question?

Comment: Sorry. Updated the question. TIL: fieldset, legend. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't this semantically incorrect - I thought fieldsets should only be used in forms

Comment: Maybe, but it's totally valid to use without forms.

Comment: So are a lot of things that are semantically incorrect like using tables for layout - doesn't mean you should do it though

Comment: You made the points, there is no definite right or wrong very often.